Azure Pipelines that share an Agent Pool are stealing the agent from each other, cancelling builds
We are running into a strange issue with our DevOps server that I've not been able to find an answer to. We have several pipelines that are set up for different branches, all running off of a single job pool with a single Build Agent. The pipelines are set up for running Gated Check-ins for each branch.
The problem arises when you check in to Branch B while a build is in process on Branch A. The build on Branch A is immediately Canceled ("The Operation Was Canceled" error) and a build is kicked off for Branch B. And vice versa.
If you check in to Branch A while Branch A is building, it properly queues up a build and waits for its turn. Not so if you are checking in to different pipelines.
Obviously, this is a problem as we're having Gated Check-in builds failing because someone checked in to a different branch before the gated build completed.
This issue arose as part of us migrating up to DevOps 2020 from either TFS 2018--I cannot remember which, will clarify once I get an answer. We were not having this problem in the old version, and we're having it now.
I feel like I must be missing something obvious--please let me know if there's any additional information I can add to help with figuring this out, I didn't want to bury the question in a bunch of possibly extraneous info.
What is misconfigured that is causing builds to steal the agent, rather than queue up, if they are triggered from separate pipelines?
YAML here:
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: $/ProjectName/Trunk
jobs:
- job: Phase_1
  displayName: Phase 1
  cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
  pool:
    name: Pool 2
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: true
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
    displayName: Use NuGet 4.4.1
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 4.4.1
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: Use NuGet 5.11.x
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 5.11.x
  - task: NuGetInstaller@0
    name: NuGetInstaller_1
    displayName: NuGet restore **\*.sln
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      solution: '**\*.sln'
      noCache: true
      nuGetPath: $(NuGetPath)
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: NuGet restore
  - task: VSBuild@1
    name: VSBuild_2
    displayName: Build solution **\*.sln
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      platform: $(BuildPlatform)
      configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
      clean: true
      msbuildArchitecture: x64
  - task: MSBuild@1
    displayName: Build solution **/*.sln
    inputs:
      msbuildLocationMethod: location
      msbuildLocation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
      platform: $(BuildPlatform)
      configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
      msbuildArguments: /p:OutDir=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
...




Adding either yaml or screenshots of gated check-in settings will help a bit.

@dropoutcoder Added them in

Thank. I am not seeing anything strange. I will try to simulate in my DevOps.

When did you created those gated builds? I was trying to create new through classic editor and the screen is different. I am wondering if the problem might not be the version of classic pipeline.

@dropoutcoder The gated checkin build for 'Trunk' (the one I shared) was originally created in 2017. However, another branch's gated build was created 2/13/2024, and its screens look the same. This is running on DevOps server 2020, Update 1.1

Didi you try to set system.debug to true under variable tab? It might give you extensive info about what is going on there.

Only relevant error I seem to be getting is this: "MSB5021: Terminating the task executable "sgen" and its child processes because the build was canceled." Which is clearly pretty useless, as that's just MSBuild telling me that it's shutting off because something hit cancel. (It doesn't always terminate on the same executable, either--depends on timing for when it cancels). Some setting, somewhere, is allowing Branch A to cancel builds for Branch B (or v/v) when a new check-in happens

Can you try to set cancelTimeoutInMinutes to a higher number? More than the build is usually running. This one instructs how long to wait for task to wait if those are set to run always, but build is cancelled.

I've seen this issue happen 20 seconds into a build. It always perfectly lines up with when a new build is queued. And it's already a higher number than the build usually runs for--the builds average about three and a half minutes.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Testing on my side, I cannot reproduce this issue. You can create a new TFVC project and check if there is the same issue in it.
